# SocketChannel write more than 1 response

Tags: java, nio, socketchannel

I am writing dummy server for my project to accept request from client and return 1 or more responses back.
On the dummy server side, it gets the request from client, and find the matched message to send back. Below is piece of code of writing part.

```
for (String line : response) {
        ByteBuffer msgBuf = ByteBuffer.wrap(line.getBytes());
        if (!ccc.isConnected())
            ccc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 50051));
        logger.info("Capacity of msgBuf is : " + msgBuf.capacity());
        ccc.write(msgBuf);
        logger.info("Seding out the response : " + line);
        msgBuf.rewind();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
```

if sever found 2 data to send back, the ccc socket will write twice.
I put Thread.sleep(2000) there, coz if I don't do this, the client side will get 2 data together. But I want the server send the data one by one.

Comment: TCP is not a messaging protocol. It is a byte stream. Your code is working correctly. NB `ServerSocketChannel` can't write anything, let alone a response, let alone more than one. Rewinding an object that is about to fall out of scope is futile. [tag:serversocket] is irrelevant.